# Change url via .htaccess on managed server

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I am currently trying to change the url output on my new managed server. I am redirecting several urls from a different provide to my managed server. In the root of that sever is a .htaccess file with the following command:

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.tld [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/$1
```

So i am pointing the domain to the created directory. Within that directory there is another .htaccess file with the following commands:

```
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine on 

ErrorDocument 401 http://www.domain.tld/error.php 
ErrorDocument 402 http://www.domain.tld/error.php 
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domain.tld/error.php 
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.tld/error.php 
ErrorDocument 405 http://www.domain.tld/error.php 
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.comain.tld/error.php 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.tld 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php
```

All of that works just fine with the exception, that if i access the domains in my browser it will show:

http://www.domain.tld/directory/

instead of

http://www.domain.tld

Out of several domains pointing to that server only one will work the way i want it to and that one is based on wordpress. The wordpress one doesn't have the .htaccess file shown above in the directory. I would really like to keep the clean urls but i also need to get rid of the directory in the domain name when you access it. If i access the domain and click on the home link in the navigation it shows the url the way i want it to. So what do i have to change in the .htaccess file to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the browser of your choice and go into the network tab. What happens after navigating to www.domain.tld? Look for 301's

Comment: There are no 301 errors at all.

Comment: 301 is no error, it's a redirect, which should occur, if you navigate to http://www.domain.tld - else the browser would not show domain/dir/

Comment: I tired it again and checked out the entire network tab. I doesn't show any 301's.

Comment: Okay then - what changes the url from domain to domain/dir? That does not happen by chance - this _is_ triggered by something. And always use a private or incognito browser while testing - caches can cause headaches...

Comment: See what happens when you change your `ErrorDocument` directives to *exclude* `http://www.domain.tld` so it becomes `/error.php`.

Comment: @TGlatzer - I don't think ingcognito disabled cache - dev tools does that, when enabled.

Comment: I gues this must be happening within the first .htaccess. In that file i am redirecting the domain to the directory. Even when i am using the incognito tab in chrome it does the same thing. As i have said in my question. When i click on the "home" link it goes back to the normal domain. So i think it must be triggered by the .htaccess file in the root of the server.

Comment: @MikeRockett I have no idea how to do that. Sorry.

Comment: It's in your `.htaccess` file in the sub directory. Change it from `ErrorDocument 401 http://www.domain.tld/error.php` to `ErrorDocument 401 /error.php`.

Comment: But do that same change for all the `ErrorDocument` directives.

Comment: @MikeRockett I changed all the ErrorDocument entries to /error.php and it has no impact at all. Nothing changes.

Comment: The code does work on my server, so not sure what is causing it. For reference, this is how I'm doing it: http://hastebin.com/uyafinacev.apache (of course, the domain is different in my case)

Comment: @MikeRockett Thank you for that link. The only difference of your .htaccess file is the [L] after the Rewrite Rule in your .htaccess of the root. I tried changing that in my one but it doesnt make a difference.
I am really wondering how to solve this. Do you have any idea on who i could turn too? My provider tells me that i am the one responsable for that.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you saying that when you enter `domain.tld` in your browser, you are *redirected* to `domain.tld/directory/`?

Comment: When i enter domain.tld in my browser i am redirected to www.domain.tld/directory/

Comment: It may be a cache problem. In developer tools, click on cog icon and select the option that allows you disable the cache whilst developer tools is open. Then, enter `domain.tld` again, and see if it it persists. If it does, then I'm not sure how I can help. Maybe someone else will be able to jump in and assist.

Comment: @MikeRockett I just tried it and it changes nothing. I have no idea how to solve this at all. But thank you very much for your help anyways. I will try to contact my provider again and see if they will be able to do something-

Comment: @MikeRockett I think i have found a solution. If i change the line
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 
to
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.tld [R=301,L] 
it works perfekt. Do you think that this would be a good solution? Or am i risking anything with it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The purpose of that condition and rule is to add `www.` in front of `domain.tld`. Omitting the request URI, as you have done, will force `domain.tld/hello` to redirect to `www.domain.tld` **without** the request URI.

Comment: Thats what i figures. But maybe i can use that line to redirect the domain.tld/directory/ to the domain.tld I will keep working on it.

Comment: There has to be a way to redirect the domain.tld/directory/ to www.domain.tld
After all on that one wordpress website it is working as well. The only other thing i could think of would be to redirect it before any source code at all in the php via header location. Although i would have to admit that this would kind of a "bush fix" so to speak.

Comment: I think i have found a solution. I have changed RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.tld 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] to
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301] And it seems to be working. I have no idea why but it does. Do you think i can leave it like that?